# Freemarker set call priority between is and get

Tags: java, freemarker

I have just started using Freemarker to generate emails.

In the data-model there are is and get methods. Freemarker call automatically the is-method at first.

```
<#list MainSubject.bookingList as booking> <tr> <td>${booking_index + 1} ${booking.participant.name} </td> </tr> </#list>
```

Is there any way to set the priority of calling getter methods?

Answer (score 2):

There's no practical way of changing that, at least as of 2.3.27. (I don't consider modifying `BeansWrapper` as practical.) Whether `isFoo()` or `getFoo()` should be called for `obj.foo` is decided by the JavaBeans Specification, more specifically by `java.beans.Introspector`, and `BeansWrapper` (and thus `DefaultObjectWrapper`) relies on that. If the API of the class with both "is" and "get" methods doesn't follow the JavaBeans rules, that can cause similar problems elsewhere as well, so the best would be to fix that API.

A possible workaround is calling the getter method directly in the template, like `obj.getFoo()` (assuming methods are exposed in that configuration).